# What is the full list of official D&D settings?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings

What are the official Wizards of the Coast / TSR D&D campaign settings?

The ones I know of off hand are the following, also it would be good to know what rule edition they initially started in and if they are no longer updated as of what edition:

- Forgotten Realms
- Dragonlance
- Eberron
- Greyhawk

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, if we're only counting the WotC ones, in no particular order:

- Dark Sun -- 3.x material in Dragon and Dungeon, and of course it just came out for 4e.
- Eberron -- winner of the setting
  search, by Keith Baker. Got a lot of
  WotC support.
- Forgotten Realms -- the
  biggest one, probably.
- Ghostwalk -- one book, interesting setting about undead.
- Greyhawk --
  lightly supported by WotC, but don't forget that WotC's organized play was mostly
  about Greyhawk!
- Mahasarpa -- Web only, Southeast Asia flavored.
- Nentir Vale (aka Points of Light) -- the default 4e setting.
- Planescape -- got mostly magazine support from WotC. Built into the 4e generic setting.
- Ravenloft -- will be an official 4e setting next year, I think.
- Rokugan -- yeah, Legends of the Five Rings. WotC published a version of Oriental Adventures using the setting, though.
- Spelljammer -- showed up in Dungeon magazine once or twice.
- Mystara - Basic D&D "Known World" -- Showed up at least in the 30th anniversary Dragon mag and maybe a few others.

Settings introduced for 5th Edition:

- Ravnica -- a *Magic the Gathering* setting published in *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*
- Wildemount, in the world of Exandria -- The setting of *Critical Role: Campaign 2*, published in *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*
- Theros -- a *Magic the Gathering* setting published in *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*

TSR ones also include:

- Blackmoor - The Original setting, different from the "Blackmoor" in Mystara
- Al-Qadim - Arabian knights
- Birthright - PCs rule countries
- Council of Wyrms - dragon PCs
- Dragonlance - based on the novels
- Jakandor - island mini-setting
- Pelinore - from Imagine magazine

I'm not counting the various subregions of the Forgotten Realms, like Maztica. I'm also not listing all the third party settings. Lots of those!

[A full list can also be found on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_campaign_settings)

Comment: There was also Kenzer&Co's Kingdoms of Kalamar setting, which, under separate license, was done by K&Co, and sold with the D&D Brand Logo.

Comment: Updated to include new 5e settings

Answer (score 6):

No one has mentioned the Hollow World setting from TSR (which, while officially part of Mystara, has a wholly different feel and product line), nor the AD&D Lankhmar and Conan modules, which while not fully fleshed out, were multi-product settings.

Comment: I'd forgot about the Lankhmar releases... oh the memories :)

Comment: Hollow World was particularly fun...

Answer (score 4):

My favorite obscure WOTC D&D campaign setting would definately have to be [Diablo II.](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/main.asp?x=d2/diabloii,3) (Diablo's Red Lightning attack ignores normal evasion, and treats improved evasion as regular evasion instead - nasty!)

Depending on how broadly you're defining "campaign setting" and "D&D", you may also want to include the various d20 Modern settings (or at least Urban Arcana), and if Spelljammer is making the list, then you're actually including content published by Paizo under license from WOTC.

And if Paizo content counts... well, you'll have to start working up a formal definition of what is and isn't D&D, because Spelljammer was published as a mini-setting in the Polyhedron mini-magazine in the back of Dungeon magazine in the early 2000s, and there were like ten mini-settings a year in that format, including a mecha system, three early precursors to d20 Modern, a sword-and-planet setting that I may have to track down, etc.

I believe WOTC also published the d20 Wheel Of Time RPG, and there was also an issue of Dragon (#307) that mostly was content for George R. R. Martin's "Song Of Ice And Fire" setting (Westeros).

Additionally, WOTC is no longer the publisher of the Dragonlance campaign setting books.

Finally, there two or three later issues of Dragon which consisted entirely of articles with bits of support for old campaign settings which were otherwise no longer supported - in some cases, for many years. Up to you if publishing content for a campaign setting counts as publishing the campaign setting.

Comment: the 3E D&D Dragonlance was by Sovereign Press... which was Margaret Weis' company (With Don Perrin; noted for Sovereign Stone and d20 Dragonlance), but the DL license ended in 2007, and reverted back to Wizards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about Spelljammer implying Paizo; I played with Spelljammer back in the 80s, definitely a TSR product.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly Kara-Tur was the setting for the original Oriental Adventures and was disconnected from other AD&D settings. A few years later I believe that it was co-opted into the Forgotten Realms.

Comment: My 1st ed OA references FR. It's easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

For 4E, the list is the default or implied setting (typically called Points of Light), Forgotten Realms, Eberron, and Dark Sun.   It sounds like Ravenloft is the setting coming in 2011.